# Popup an iframe or website when button pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I was planning on making a popup when a button is pressed that it would dim the background. Like opening an image in Facebook, but my popup is filled with textbox for example First name, Last name, Middle name, user name, and password. I was thinking if how can I achieve that? I tried reading pirobox and fancybox but didn't get it. I think I need an online script where I could just call it. Can you guys suggest on how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/)

In this page you can see a lot of examples.

There are several iframe examples.

javascript code

```
$("#various5").fancybox({
        'width'             : '75%',
        'height'            : '75%',
        'autoScale'         : false,
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none',
        'type'              : 'iframe'
    });
```

HTML code

```
<a id="various5" href="/data/iframe.html">Iframe (75% width and height)</a>
```

You load fancybox library and initialize fancybox object. When you click in your link with iframe url href the popup shows iframe content

Comment: Do I need to download and put the whole library to my website to make it work?

Comment: you must load the library on the page in which you use , but it would be desirable to have it loaded jquery globally.

Comment: Do I need the js file only?

Comment: jquery, fancybox javascript and fancybox css

Answer (score 0):

If you can use bootstrap,
then "modals" will do what you want: 
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Put your iframe inside the "modal-body"

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yourCSSPath/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="yourJsPath/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="yourJsPath/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="myModal">
...
     <div class="modal-body" id="miniWindow">
     </div>
...
</div>

<a href="javascript:showIframe('page.html')">Button</a>

<script>
function showIframe(url){
    code = "<iframe src='/yourPathForTheIframes/" + url + "'></iframe>";
    $("#miniShow").html(code);
    $("#myModal").show();
}
</script>
```

Comment: How do i call the iframe when triggered by a button?

Comment: with jQuery: $(".modal-body").html("<iframe src='.....'></iframe>"); $("#mymodal").show();

Comment: Can you explain to me the code that you just sent? I not kinda familiar with jquery.

Answer (score 0):

[Modal Dialogs](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form) with jQuery UI should solve your issue